# How to mutate a vector's elements while iterating through it?

Tags: rust

I'm iterating through a vector and I want to change one of the elements.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    for (i, el) in vector.iter().enumerate() {
        if i == 0 {
            continue;
        }
        vector[i - 1] += el
    }
}
```

This gives me the compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vector` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
4 |     for (i, el) in vector.iter().enumerate() {
  |                    ------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
8 |         vector[i - 1] += el
  |         ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
9 |     }
  |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

I understand why this error occurs. I am borrowing vector as immutable for the lifetime of the enumeration scope and then trying to mutate the interior inside that scope thus breaking the borrowing rules. I just don't understand how to do this properly. I guess I need to borrow mutably for the enumeration?

I've tried various combinations of `mut`, `&mut` and I run into different compiler errors with each. I know I could make this a `Vec<Cell<i32>>` and mutate the contents that way, but this seems overkill for such a simple example.

Comment: side note, there's also [iter_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use indexing.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    for i in 1..vector.len() {
        vector[i - 1] += vector[i];
    }

    println!("{:?}", vector);
}
```

Comment: You'd think they'd have a `windows_mut` function like [`chunks_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.chunks_mut) over [windows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.windows), which would handle this quite handily, but alas.

Comment: @BHustus: They *can't*.  Iterators can't require that you drop an item before generating the next one.  Mutable references to single items is fine because you can only ever get *one* to each element.

Comment: On a more constructive note, rather than `if i == 0 { continue }`, it would be far more idiomatic to simply start at `1`: `for i in 1..vector.len()`, unless there's more operation necessary in that `if` block. This goes for the original example provided in the question as well.

Comment: @BHustus: Good point.  I usually translate examples like that as exactly as possible to keep a minimal number of changes... but, yeah, that case is hopefully obvious enough.

Comment: Well, that's why I specified that it goes for the original example as well. I get the whole "keep the example" issue. In such cases I usually add the modification as a side note at the bottom of the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I left wondering how this fits into the lifetime rules. My presumption (probably wrong) is that `vector[i]` is borrowing vector immutably and `vector[i - 1] +=` has to borrow the vector mutably at the same time so I'm not sure why that is ok to do. Or does the immutable borrow end as soon as a immutable reference to the inner i32 is returned?

Comment: If I try to write this out without the syntactic sugar, I get the borrowing error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=82aaa1e6b6ae3250e5756617dfef17a5&version=stable. Is there some compiler magic happening to allow this?

Comment: Actually maybe I wrote it wrong. This works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2841197f9a6edc76b3f8de356c12c959&version=stable. I guess by dereferencing the reference, the borrow ends and the rules are satisfied.

Comment: @MattHarrison: As you appear to have realised: indexing does borrow, but it only borrows for as long as it takes to read/write the value being accessed.  An iterator borrows for as long as iteration goes on.

Comment: @BHustus Supporting this kind of windowed iterator is the motivating example in [RFC-1598 generic_associated_type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md)